# Do black holes exist?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, information

Do [black holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) exist from our point of reference? From our point of reference nothing actually goes inside the event horizon right? So is there anything inside the event horizon from our reference? If not then no black holes actually exist  but hollow spheres that have the center of mass inside them? So no information paradox :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95555/in-there-such-a-thing-as-the-black-hole-information-paradox?rq=1 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47669/black-hole-formation-as-seen-by-a-distant-observer?rq=1 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21319/how-can-anything-ever-fall-into-a-black-hole-as-seen-from-an-outside-observer?rq=1 (It's a good insight, and I'd go so far as to say it's a correct one, but we've covered it before.)

Comment: I've linked the most recent duplicate I can remember. There have been many such duplicates over the years. My answer to the linked question is my current best effort at illuminating the problem though I remain unconvinced there is a good explanation for non-nerds.

Comment: Ive read some answers but Im still not sure that any of the answers did explicitly answer the question if any black holes exist  from our reference according to current theories.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "from our point of reference."

Comment: From the reference of earth.

Comment: @John Rennie  This is not a duplicate, because the other questions ask for the time for BH formation, while this one asks whether a BH can be cosidered as such if it has no information inside.

Comment: @Nathaniel it is not a duplicate

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar I'm asking if it is correct to say that black holes exists from our point of reference, because from our point of reference nothing is inside them. Nothing is inside them, as I understand it, because nothing ever goes through the event horizon from our point of reference.